# How to places two divs in one row: one fixed, other is stretched

Tags: html

I need two div boxes: one at left side with fixed width, and other on the right side of first and it should stretch to right side.
How to do this?

```
/-- 30px --//------ * -------/
|          |                 |
|          |                 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better not to use absolute position, since you may want to place it within other elements.
That's what works for me:

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 30px">1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div style="left:0;width:30px;"></div>
<div style="left:30px;right:0;"></div>
```

You may need to make them absolute positioned and the parent relative.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a load of CSS-layouts, that page should give you the answer:

http://tjkdesign.com/articles/one_html_markup_many_css_layouts.asp

Comment: They are all stretched (width in %) =(